# How to convert LDAP data (NTEXT) to String within an SSIS Package?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ssis, ldap

I'm currently using LDAP to grab User information within an SSIS package. I'm using an ADO.NET Datasource which is running this query:

```
SELECT sAMAccountName, cn, givenName, sn FROM 'LDAP://domainController' where objectClass='User'
```

The problem is, I would like to append the Domain suffix to the sAMAccountName since it is not included. Ex. " **DOMAIN\** sAMAccountName" . However, I cannot figure out how to convert this data from Unicode Text Stream (DT_NTEXT) to String (DT_STR). Converting this column to String will allow me to append this suffix fairly easily using the Derived Column tool.

Is there a simple way of converting a DT_NTEXT to a DT_STR within my SSIS package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Active Directory SSIS Data Source](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/04/active-directory-ssis-data-source.html)

I chain two data conversion tasks together "NTEXT -> TEXT" and then "TEXT -> STR" as you can see in the second screen shot. I don't have access to that package at the moment but something like 128 characters should be sufficiently wide.

Comment: In Addition, I am having another issue with the ADO.NET Source throwing an error. If you wouldn't mind taking a look, I've opened up a new thread. Thanks!